# Create task in MS project 2013 across non-continuous timespan

Tags: c#, ms-project, psi

I am trying to create task in MS project API.

It's okay when i create just one day or two days in sequence but I have problem when I create two days or more not in sequence, for example I want create in Monday and Wednesday, I just use different TASK_START_DATE and TASK_FINISH_DATE, but it's not working.

Here is my code to create task in project 2013

```
        SvcProject.ProjectDataSet newProjectData = new SvcProject.ProjectDataSet();

        // Add a new task.
        SvcProject.ProjectDataSet.TaskRow newTask = newProjectData.Task.NewTaskRow();

        newTask.PROJ_UID = new Guid(projectUID);
        newTask.TASK_UID = new Guid(taskUID);
        newTask.TASK_DUR_FMT = taskDurationFormat;
        newTask.TASK_DUR = taskDuration;
        newTask.TASK_NAME = taskName;
        newTask.TASK_START_DATE = taskStartDate; // will change later
        newTask.TASK_FINISH_DATE = taskFinishDate;
        newProjectData.Task.AddTaskRow(newTask);

        jobUID = Guid.NewGuid();
        projectClient.QueueAddToProject(jobUID, new Guid(sessionUID), newProjectData, false);
```

how is it not working, is when i use START_DATE in monday and FINISH_DATE in wednesday, and just DURATION with 9600 (2 days) after execute it, i open file and the result is i got in sequence, and in monday is just a quarter day, tuesday 8 hours, and wednesday just a quarted day too. what i want is monday 8 hours - tuesday 0 hour, wednesday 8 hour

i got unexpected result

Comment: *but it's not working* - **How** is it not working? Do you get an error? Do you get unexpected results? Does it start raining pianos? Please describe the nature of your problem!

Comment: sorry if not clear, how is it not working, is when i use START_DATE in monday and FINISH_DATE in wednesday, and just DURATION with 9600 (2 days) after execute it, i open file and the result is i got  in sequence, and in monday is just a quarter day, tuesday 8 hours, and wednesday just a quarted day too. what i want is monday 8 hours - tuesday 0 hour, wednesday 8 hour

Comment: You first need to understand how MS Project works before you can automate it. The whole point of MS Project is that it does the scheduling for you. So don't give it a duration AND a start AND a finish. Also, if Tuesday is a working day, Project will show the task working on that day unless you assign a resource that doesn't work on that day. Or unless you split the task (an advanced topic...) Bottom line: it is beyond the scope of a SO answer to resolve your issues. You need to learn how the application works before you set about automating it in a way that simply doesn't make sense,